# Angular JS Routing to different Page from ng-template popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-routing, angularjs-ng-template

We have decided to use **ng-template** as a popover container which loads the contents in the  tags.

**....

....**

I also have this popup's controller and I am able to alert values from this controller. The only thing **I am not able to do is route to different page** when I say **conversation/new**

If I put a sample button or link in the home page then it routes to the second page but not from the popover.

One thing that is happening - URL which I want is flashing and then reseting to what it was.

Has any one faced such issue? Is it a known issue or there is a work around to this.

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: can you use ui-bootstrap?

Comment: I am using Angular Bootstrap... Cant it be done with this? @CallumLinington

Comment: Use the modal form then?

Comment: could you give me a JS Lint?